# Create a dictionary from list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The following code gives me the output as displayed below.  I would like to take each of the numbers following the respective category and put them into a dictionary.  What is an efficient way to do so?

Current Code:

```
d = {}
data = []

contentB = tree.xpath("//table[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']/tr[1]/td/table/tr/td")

for a in contentB:
    a = a.text_content().strip()
    data.extend(a.splitlines())

for item in data:

    if re.match(r'\(\d+', item) is not None:
        item = item.replace('(', '-').replace(')', '')

        print(item)
```

Output

```
Period Ending
Total Revenue
31821000
30871000
29904000
Cost of Revenue
16447000
16106000
15685000
Gross Profit
15374000
14765000
14219000
Operating Expenses
Research Development
1770000
1715000
1634000
```

Desired Outcome

```
{
    'Total Revenue': [31821000, 30871000, 29904000],
    'Cost of Revenue': [16447000, 16106000, 15685000],
    'Gross Profit': [15374000, 14765000, 14219000]
}
```

Comment: Are the blocks of header/numbers always in groups of three?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
output = {}
current_key = None
for item in data:
    if re.match(r'\(\d+', item) is None:
        current_key = item.replace('(', '-').replace(')', '')
        output[current_key] = []
    else:
        if current_key:
            output[current_key].append(int(item.replace(',', '')))

print output
```

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Net Income From Continuing Ops'`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Eugene Soldatov's answer, I've tried to automatically identify data breaks. I'm using the locale package though since your data seems to use commas for separating units. You may have to adjust the second line to your locale. Untested because I don't use a locale with that formatting ;-)

```
import locale
#locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')

summary = {}
current_key = None
for line in data:
    try
        if current_key:
            summary[current_key].append(locale.atoi(line.strip()))
    except ValueError:
        current_key = line.strip()
        summary[current_key] = []
```

Comment: I updated the data recently and turned all numbers to integers

Comment: I think the example code should work without setting the locale then.